# Fortran subroutine delivers wrong result when called in C++ program

Tags: fortran, inverse

I have to write a Fortran routine returning the inverse matrix.  If I run the code below in a Fortran program the inverse matrix is correct, but when I run the subroutine from C++ code my first value is a wrong value.  It seems like a problem with the data types or the memory.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the subroutine:

```
    subroutine get_inverse_matrix( matrix, rows_matrix, cols_matrix, tmpMatrix, rows_tmpMatrix, cols_tmpMatrix) bind(c)
        use iso_c_binding
        integer :: m, n, lda, lwork, info, size_m
        integer(c_int) :: rows_matrix, cols_matrix, rows_tmpMatrix, cols_tmpMatrix
        real(c_double) :: matrix(rows_matrix, cols_matrix), tmpMatrix(rows_tmpMatrix, cols_tmpMatrix)
        integer, dimension( rows_matrix ) :: ipiv
        real, dimension( rows_matrix )  :: work
        size_m = rows_matrix
        m = size_m
        n = size_m
        lda = size_m
        lwork = size_m
        write(*,*) "Matrix: ", matrix
        !tmpMatrix = matrix
        write(*,*) "Temp matrix: ", tmpMatrix
        ! LU-Faktorisierung (Dreieckszerlegung) der Matrix
        call sgetrf( m, n, tmpMatrix, lda, ipiv, info )
        write(*,*) info
        ! Inverse der LU-faktorisierten Matrix
        call sgetri( n, tmpMatrix, lda, ipiv, work, lwork, info )
        write(*,*) info
        select case(info)
            case(0)
            write(*,*) "SUCCESS"
            case(:-1)
            write(*,*) "ILLEGAL VALUE"
            case(1:)
            write(*,*) "SINGULAR MATRIX"
        end select
    end subroutine get_inverse_matrix
```

Here is the declaration in the C++ code:

```
extern "C"
{
void get_inverse_matrix( double *matrix, int *rows_matrix, int *cols_matrix, double *tmpMatrix, int *rows_tmpMatrix, int *cols_tmpMatrix);}
```

Here is the call from my C++ program:

```
get_inverse_matrix(&lhs[0], &sz, &sz, &res[0], &sz, &sz);
```

My program only uses a 3x3 matrix.  If I pass the identity matrix the result looks like:

```
5.29981e-315 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1
```

Comment: You are passing a array declared as type `c_double` to lapack routines which expect single precision, this can sometimes cause problems. Can you try replacing `sgetrf` and `sgetri` with `dgetrf` and `dgetri` and does this help? I wouldn't have expected the fortran to work either in this case. Note you probably should show the declarations in the C++ code as well.

Comment: i added the declaration in c++ code. Also I replaced as you called, but the result is a matrix with only Zeros, doesnt matter what values i tried.

Comment: It is much better to use modern Fortran90+ interface module to LAPACK or at least to have an interface block to check the call for errors.

Comment: Also in your code provided you pass in matrix but then don't use it for anything (other than printing) as you've commented out the line `tmpMatrix = matrix`. Is this correct or just a typo here? Are `matrix` and/or `tmpMatrix` (i.e. `lhs` and/or `res`) initialised in your C++ code?

Comment: thanks for noticing this. While trying to fix i commented out the line. with the line in use and the dgetrf and dgetri calls it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend using an editor with syntax highlighting if possible as it can help make these sorts of issues more obvious.

Comment: i will try next time. i was just editing the code in qt-creator, but the language wasnt recognized, so no highlighting. Another question for an new user: how can i mark this question as answered an how can i recommend your answer?

Comment: I've posted an explicit answer that addresses the key issue. If this is an answer you wish to accept you can click the small tick next to the answer (and optionally vote). This will mark the question as having an accepted answer. Note you can change which answer you want to accept if someone posts a better answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring your arrays as type `real` with kind `c_double` but you are using lapack routines that are expecting single precision inputs (e.g. `c_float`). To fix this you should replace the calls to `sgetrf` and `sgetri` with `dgetrf` and `dgetri`.

As noted by Vladimir F in the comments these issues can be more easily caught if you provide interfaces.